# sunspot_solr on rails error info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sunspot, searchable

RSolr::Error::Http in CoursesController#index

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error:     NOT_FOUND

Request Data: "fq=type%3ACourse&start=0&rows=30&q=%2A%3A%2A"

Backtrace: /Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:268:in `adapt_response'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `execute'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.9/lib/rsolr/client.rb:161:in `send_and_receive'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:45:in `execute'
/Users/gabriel/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:344:in `solr_execute_search'
```

I followed the ***278-search-with-sunspot***, when I modified the index function and start the server, the above error message was thrown. Anyone can help?